# Moodle Login page Change

Tags: php, html, css, logic, moodle

I'm trying to add new fields in moodle login page. I'm simply editing the `index_form.html` in login folder.
I'm using evolve theme and using moodle version `2.8`
I want a dropdown field for administrator, teacher and student. If user selects administrator or teacher they have the fields of username and password, but if student is been selected one extra field of Adhar number is added for validation dynamically. 
I have created the fields just need to add it to database and conditional logic. In the backend of user profile fields I've added a custom user fields under the name of Adhar Number whose short name I've kept as Adharno, lot of things more is to be done and I'm unable to find path, following is the link below with `html` code and `css`
[www.sanskritiskills.com/assessment/login/index.php](http://www.sanskritiskills.com/assessment/login/index.php)

Code block:

```
<?php
if ($show_instructions) {
    $columns = 'twocolumns';
} else {
$columns = 'onecolumn';
}

if (!empty($CFG->loginpasswordautocomplete)) {
    $autocomplete = 'autocomplete="off"';
} else {
    $autocomplete = '';
}
if (empty($CFG->authloginviaemail)) {
    $strusername = get_string('username');
} else {
    $strusername = get_string('usernameemail');
}
?>
<div class="loginbox clearfix <?php echo $columns ?>">
  <div class="loginpanel">
<?php
   if (($CFG->registerauth == 'email') || !empty($CFG->registerauth)) { ?>
      <div class="skiplinks"><a class="skip" href="signup.php"><?php print_string("tocreatenewaccount"); ?></a></div>
<?php
  } ?>
    <h2><?php print_string("login") ?></h2>
      <div class="subcontent loginsub">
        <?php
          if (!empty($errormsg)) {
               echo html_writer::start_tag('div', array('class' => 'loginerrors'));
          echo html_writer::link('#', $errormsg, array('id' => 'loginerrormessage', 'class' => 'accesshide'));
          echo $OUTPUT->error_text($errormsg);
          echo html_writer::end_tag('div');
      }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $CFG->httpswwwroot; ?>/login/index.php" method="post" id="login" <?php echo $autocomplete; ?> >
      <div class="loginform">     
       <div class="form-input">
       Select Role :
       <select required>
       <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
       <option value="Student">Student</option>
       <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
       </select>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
        <div class="form-label"><label for="username"><?php echo($strusername) ?></label></div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="15" value="<?php p($frm->username) ?>" />
       </div>
        <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
        <div class="form-label"><label for="password"><?php print_string("password") ?></label></div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="15" value="" <?php echo $autocomplete; ?> />
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
        <div class="form-label"><label for="password">Adhar No.</label></div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="password" name="Adhar Number" id="password" size="15" value="" <?php echo $autocomplete; ?> />
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
          <?php if (isset($CFG->rememberusername) and $CFG->rememberusername == 2) { ?>
          <div class="rememberpass">
              <input type="checkbox" name="rememberusername" id="rememberusername" value="1" <?php if ($frm->username) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> />
              <label for="rememberusername"><?php print_string('rememberusername', 'admin') ?></label>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
      <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
      <input type="submit" id="loginbtn" value="<?php print_string("login") ?>" />
      <div class="forgetpass"><a href="forgot_password.php"><?php print_string("forgotten") ?></a></div>
    </form>
    <div class="desc">
        <?php
            echo get_string("cookiesenabled");
            echo $OUTPUT->help_icon('cookiesenabled');
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php if ($CFG->guestloginbutton and !isguestuser()) {  ?>
      <div class="subcontent guestsub">
    <div class="desc">
      <?php print_string("someallowguest") ?>
    </div>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="guestlogin">
      <div class="guestform">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="guest" />
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="guest" />
        <input type="submit" value="<?php print_string("loginguest") ?>" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
     </div>
<?php if ($show_instructions) { ?>
    <div class="signuppanel">
  <h2><?php print_string("firsttime") ?></h2>
  <div class="subcontent">
<?php     if (is_enabled_auth('none')) { // instructions override the rest for security reasons
          print_string("loginstepsnone");
      } else if ($CFG->registerauth == 'email') {
          if (!empty($CFG->auth_instructions)) {
              echo format_text($CFG->auth_instructions);
          } else {
              print_string("loginsteps", "", "signup.php");
          } ?>
             <div class="signupform">
               <form action="signup.php" method="get" id="signup">
               <div><input type="submit" value="<?php print_string("startsignup") ?>" /></div>
               </form>
             </div>
<?php     } else if (!empty($CFG->registerauth)) {
          echo format_text($CFG->auth_instructions); ?>
          <div class="signupform">
            <form action="signup.php" method="get" id="signup">
            <div><input type="submit" value="<?php print_string("startsignup") ?>" /></div>
            </form>
          </div>
<?php     } else {
          echo format_text($CFG->auth_instructions);
      } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($potentialidps)) { ?>
<div class="subcontent potentialidps">
    <h6><?php print_string('potentialidps', 'auth'); ?></h6>
    <div class="potentialidplist">
<?php foreach ($potentialidps as $idp) {
echo  '<div class="potentialidp"><a href="' . $idp['url']->out() . '" title="' . $idp['name'] . '">' . $OUTPUT->render($idp['icon'], $idp['name']) . $idp['name'] . '</a></div>';
} ?>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**CSS File** which is available:

```
/* evolved CSS
-------------------------*/
#dock {background: #32352c; }

.arrow {color: #3d3d3d; }

.block .header h2 {color: #3d3d3d;}

.dir-rtl a.logo {
background: url([[setting:logo]]) no-repeat 100% 0;
display: block;
float: right;
}

.pagelayout-report .no-overflow {
overflow: auto;
}

.service {
display:block;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px;
text-align:left;
    background-color: [[setting:marketboxcolor]];
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
}

#fullbkg { 
  background: url([[setting:fpbkg]]) no-repeat center center fixed;  
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*Frontpage Login*/
.wrap {
width:250px;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.avatarlogin {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
width: 65px;
border-radius: 100px;
height: 65px;
background: #000 ;
position: relative;
bottom: -15px;
}
.avatarlogin img {
width: 55px;
height: 55px;
border-radius: 100px;
margin: auto;
border:3px solid #fff;
display: block;
}
.wrap input {
border: none;
background: #fff;
  font-family:Lato ;
  font-weight:700 ;
display: block;
height: 40px;
outline: none;
width: calc(100% - 24px) ;
margin: auto;
padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
}
    .bar {
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background: #fff ;
}
.bar i {
width: 95%;
margin: auto;
height: 1px ;
display: block;
background: #d1d1d1;
}
.wrap input[type="text"] {
border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px ;
}
.wrap input[type="password"] {
border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px ;
}
.forgot_link {
color: #83afdf ;
color: #83afdf;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 11px;
position: relative;
left: 193px;
top: -36px;
}
.wrap button {
width: 100%;
border-radius: 7px;
background: #b6ee65;
text-decoration: center;
border: none;
color: #51771a;
margin-top:-5px;
padding-top: 14px;
padding-bottom: 14px;
outline: none;
font-size: 20px;    
border-bottom: 3px solid #307d63;
cursor: pointer;
}

    /*.loginbox {
background: rgba(100,100,100,.1);
padding:50px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}*/

.loginbox h2{
color: #DBDBDB;
text-align:center;
}

.loginbox form a{
color: #fff;
}
.loginbox form{
color: #fff;
}
.loginbox p{
color: #fff;
}

/*.loginpanel .loginsub {
background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
margin: 10px;
}*/

.loginpanel .loginsub {
background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
max-width:400px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
border:5px solid #fff;
margin: auto;
padding:20px;
}
.signuppanel .subcontent{
background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
max-width:400px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
box-shadow: 1px 0px 29px 14px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
margin: auto;
}

/* Alerts (aardvark) */
#page-header-generalalert {
clear:both;
display: block;
color:#ff9f00;
background-color:#fef8d2;
padding:8px 35px 8px 14px;
margin-bottom:20px;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
border:1px solid #fde6af;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
}

#page-header-generalalert:before {
background-color: #ff9f00;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-size: 1.2em;
height: 1.4em;
margin-right: 0.5em;
margin-top: -0.15em;
margin-left: -0.5em;
padding-top: 0.2em;
text-align: center;
width: 1.7em;
content:"\f06a";
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
text-shadow:none;
}

#page-header-snowalert {
clear:both;
display: block;
color:#3a87ad;
background-color:#d9edf7;
padding:8px 35px 8px 14px;
margin-bottom:20px;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
border:1px solid #bce8f1;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
}

#page-header-snowalert:before {
background-color: #3a87ad;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-size: 1.2em;
height: 1.4em;
margin-right: 0.5em;
margin-top: -0.15em;
margin-left: -0.5em;
padding-top: 0.2em;
text-align: center;
width: 1.7em;
content:"\f069";
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
text-shadow:none;
}


 /*Google Fonts (Theme Essential)*/

/* @group Headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
.back-to-top,
.socials p,
#socialheading,
.forumpost .subject,
.block_login label {
font-family: "[[setting:headingfont]]", sans-serif;
}
/* @group Main Text */
body,
.block_login input[type="submit"] {
font-family: "[[setting:bodyfont]]", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: [[setting:bodysize]];
font-weight: [[setting:bodyweight]];
}
/* @end */

/*Special thanks to Shaun Daubney (Theme Aardvark)
for the colored icons in the blocks.
 */

.block .header .title h2:before {
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-size: 1.2em;
height: 1.3em;
margin-left: -0.5em;
margin-right: 0.5em;
margin-top: -0.2em;
padding-top: 0.2em;
text-align: center;
width: 1.5em;
-webkit-border-radius:2px;
-moz-border-radius:2px;
border-radius:2px;
}

.block_news_items .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #29A294;
content:"\f0a1";
}

.block_navigation .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #f42941;
content:"\f0e8";
}

.block_calendar_upcoming .header .title h2:before,
.block_calendar_month .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #008ecd;
content:"\f073";
}

.block_course_list .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ffce00;
content:"\f108";
}

.block_completionstatus .header .title h2:before,
.block_selfcompletion .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #76b900;
content:"\f0e4";
}

.block_rss_client .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ff9500;
content:"\f09e";
}

.block_rss_plus .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ff9500;
content:"\f09e";
}

.block_blog_menu .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ff9500;
content:"\f02d";
}

.block_quiz_results .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #76b900;    
content:"\f080";
}

.block_quiz_navblock .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #76b900;
content:"\f126";
}

.block_glossary_random .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #3d3d3d;
content:"\f0eb";
}

.block_book_toc .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #3d3d3d;
content:"\f02d";
}


.block_participants .header .title h2:before,
.block_online_users .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #92499e;
content:"\f0c0";
}

.block_html .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #eeeeee;

}

.block_section_links .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #f42941;
content:"\f02e";
}

.block_activity_modules .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #f42941;
content:"\f12e";
}

.block_comments .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ffce00;
content:"\f075";
}

.block_settings .header .title h2:before,
.block_admin_bookmarks .header .title h2:before{
background-color: #004675;
content:"\f085";
}

.block_blog_tags .header .title h2:before,
.block_tags .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ff9f00;
content:"\f02c";
}

.block_private_files .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #82cadd;
content:"\f114";
}

.block_block_mentees .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #3d3d3d;
content:"\f0c0";
}

.block_messages .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ffce00;
content:"\f0e0";
}

.block_community .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ffce00;
content:"\f0ac";
}

.block_login .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #3d3d3d;
content:"\f007";
}

.block_recent_activity .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #cee3ed;
content:"\f017";
}

.block_search_forums .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ffce00;
content:"\f0e6";
}

.block_myprofile .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #f42941;
content:"\f007";
}

.block_adminblock .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #E0F52A;
content:"\f055";
}

.block_feedback .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ffce00;
content:"\f087";
}

.block_flickr .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #ff3096;
content:"\f03e";
}

.block_youtube .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #f42941;
content:"\f145";
}

.block_course_badges .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #29a294;
content:"\f091";
}

.block_twitter_search .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #008ecd;
content:"\f099";
}

.block_heritage .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #3e647e;
content:"\f02d";
}

.block_lrc .header .title h2:before {
background-color: #3e647e;
content:"\f02d";
}


 /*Social Wall*/

 .format-socialwall .course-content ul.topics li.section {
 border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
 margin-top: 0;
 }

/*.mform {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}*/
.format-socialwall #section-2 .content {
background-color: #f7f7f7;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0px;
border: 3px solid #d4d4d4;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #ccc;
}
.tl-post {
margin: 30px 0px 50px 0px;
padding:15px;
}
.tl-posttext {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
//border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-top: 10px;
}

ul.section.tl-postattachment {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 50px;
//border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
//border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
margin:0px;
}
.tl-text {
margin-left: 40px;
padding: 0 5px;
border: 2px solid #efefef;
padding: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #e7e7e7;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #e7e7e7;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #e7e7e7;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
/*.tl-text {
margin-left: 40px;
//border: none;
border: 1px solid #efefef;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
padding:7px;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}*/

.tl-comments {
background-color: #f7f7f7;
padding:15px;
margin:0px;
}

.tl-comment {
padding-left:25px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.tl-post-actionarea {
//border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 4px 4px 10px 4px;
//background: #F0F3F7;
//border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
.tl-timeago, .tl-counts {
font-size: 12px;
color: #666;
line-height: 15px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.like {
border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
background: #65a9d7;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#65a9d7));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
padding: 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.like:hover {
border-top-color: #28597a;
background: #28597a;
color: #ccc;
}

.like:active {
border-top-color: #1b435e;
background: #1b435e;
}

.likenomore {
border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
background: #65a9d7;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#65a9d7));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
padding: 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.likenomore:hover {
border-top-color: #28597a;
background: #28597a;
color: #ccc;
}
.likenomore:active {
border-top-color: #1b435e;
background: #1b435e;
}

form.tl-commentform {
padding-top: 10px;
}

#postform .fitem .felement #id_submitbutton {
margin:0px;
}
```

Please help me out in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking here - Is it the backend element or is it the frontend element that you're struggling with?

The easiest way (not the best way) to achieve what you're doing here is to hide the extra field if the user selects a non-student role. This is just basic JavaScript.

The script you're looking for looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "Student") {
                $(".test").show();
            }

            if ($(this).attr("value") != "Student") {
                $(".test").hide();
            }

        });
    }).change();
});
```

[**And here's the Fiddle to see it in action.**](http://jsfiddle.net/z65dfb1x/)

HTH

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks a lot and was looking for exactly the same, shall i put this function in index_form.html or shall i put this in index.php file, sorry if my question is too dumb. And the thing is I was struggling with both backend and frontend. Now the backend is resolved can you help me with the frontend, thats why I've inserted the css file. and the problem is evolve theme has two type of login page and I'm confused where to change this. links are [Homepage](http://sanskritiskills.com/assessment/) [Loginpage](http://sanskritiskills.com/assessment/login/index.php) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, glad it helped. I would put this in the HTML file in <Script> tags. I think it will still work in the PHP file if you put it as an Echo. But it's simpler to just put it in the HTML file. If you're happy with this solution, you don't need to worry about the backend element. The only problem may occur if someone selects admin/teacher AND enter an Adhar number. But your system should ignore it anyway since the admin/teacher credentials don't require the additional Adhar number. So it *should* work fine. You don't need to do anything else. :)

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the help but I've a doubt what will happen when someone selects admin/teacher and uses the student login credential, sorry to bother you but I guess we need a validation at this point.

Comment: If your login script for admins/teachers doesn't require an Adhar number, the field will just be ignored and the login block will work just fine :) If your login script does **not** ignore Adhar numbers for admins/teachers, then yes you'll need to add some validation.

Comment: Hey Tim, was not on my desk, sorry for the delay response, I tried inserting it but I'm still stuck with the same as you can see the [page source file](view-source:http://sanskritiskills.com/assessment/login/index.php) I've already inserted the script in line number 87 but its not showing the result as desired. Sorry for bothering you more n more.

Comment: That's because you haven't changed my code. You just copied and pasted it. It won't work like that. You need to change ".test" to the name of the class of your adhar field.

Comment: Hey Tim, Thanks for your continuous support, I've successfully integrated the thing, now I messed up with the alignment of the drop-down box. Please help me out in this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's because you've put the whole thing in a "form-input" class. You need to put "Select Role:" in a "form-label" class and the text field goes in a "form-input" class.